# Spring JPA can't user word 'match' as a name of database table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I create `Entity`class

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "MATCH") 
public class Match { 
...variables,getters and setters... 
}
```

In MySQL I have database table named `match`.

Also I have `JpaRepository`

```
public interface MatchRepository extends JpaRepository<Match, Long>{
}
```

And when I try to load data by `Contoller` using `MatchRepository.findAll()`, errors told me :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match match0_' at line 1
```

Can somebody explain me why MySQL don't allow me to use the database table name like `match` ? 
When I used for example name `match1` it's OK!

```
@Entity 
    @Table(name = "MATCH1") 
    public class Match { 
    ...variables,getters and setters... 
    }
```

WHY ?! 
I need this name `match` because I write project about football....

Comment: FWIW some JPA providers will auto-quote any schema names that are reserved keywords ... evidently yours doesn't.

Comment: Happened with table name user in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` is a keyword in MySQL look this example:

```
   SELECT MATCH(id, name, surname) AGAINST('milan')...
```

To know more go to [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: So what I should do ? Other name that represents Match in football is inelegant :/

Comment: you can try to search a synonyms of match

Comment: You can also just use the plural 'matches', which works just fine (though I would keep it consistent across all tables)